# XOM or DOM approach for writing XML?

Tags: xml, dom, xom

Which approach would be better to use as per the memory and usage context.
DOM or XOM? for simple writing XML.

Good Day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check my question and answer in the below question.
[XML Parsing performance DOM vs XOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209578/xml-parsing-performance-dom-vs-xom)

I tried both using the same algorithm.

They had the same CPU time. XOM Parser was 70% faster when it comes to Up time of the whole process. XOM parser had 25% smaller memory foot print as well. However, XOM needs more lines when it comes to coding as you need to loop through elements and cast nodes to elements yourself.

Regards